# Grid view item not hightlight when press

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

My app has a grid view, By default, Its item does not highlight when I click on it (I don't know why? ). I try to add it a list selector as below, But it does not work too,

```
<GridView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/load_more_process_id"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/grid_selector"
                 >
            </GridView>
```

Here my selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white"></item>
```

Comment: The highlight color is black, what is the background color?

Comment: the background color is transparent, the parent view background is white...

Comment: are you using a custom adapter? if so, use your selectors on the custom inflated viewgroups instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a focusable element in the list item contents (or the views for each grid item), the selector isn't drawn

For example, if the template for your list items is:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" ... >
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox" ... />
    <TextView android:id+"@+id/textView" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

then ListView will not draw a selector for each ListView item, because the CheckBox is, by default, focusable.

You can either provide a background on each item that changes with selection state, or disable focus on all focusable elements (which in turn requires you to write a fairy fancy adapter to check the checkboxes when selection state changes.

eg:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:focusable="false" ... />
```

will cause an enclosing ListView to start drawing the selector again.

Example of a stateful drawable:

drawable/my_list_selector_bg.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background_focused"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
 </selector>
```

You then apply that to the background of each view returned by your adapter:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
      android:background="@drawable/my_list_selector_bg"
  ... >
```

Either approach will work.

The list adpater classes (GridView, ListView, &c) call hasFocusable() on each view returned by the adapter, and disable selection drawing if hasFocusable() returns true. Fortunately, they also replicate the selection/focus/pressed/active state to the currently focused or selected adapter item, so you can draw it yourself if you want.

Comment: A frequent pitfall: putting a checkbox in the list-item tempate.

Comment: (Edited original post to provide examples).

Comment: Thinking about my experience with composite control list views in retrospect.... If you mess with the default behaviour, you will need to give serious thought to how you're going to handle focus, and keypad navigation on devices that have DPAD or trackball navigation. Google TV devices are the nost notable example, and use DPAD navigation by default -- although users can switch to touch mode if they have to. If you have a device with an outbound USB port, you can simulate the experience by plugging a PC keyboard into the USB port, and navigating using the cursor keys.(Or a Bluetooth keyboard).

Answer (score 9):

For those of you who are having the same issue I was, try

**gridView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);**

I have an ImageView and a TextView in each of my GridView items. My selector was working, but it was drawing behind my image.

Answer (score -1):

1. Layout of grid view:

   ```
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:listSelector="@drawable/gridselector"/>
   ```
2. Create custom selector gridselector.xml like:

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selector_item">
      <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/focus_offfocus">
     </item>

      <item 
         android:state_enabled="true" 
         android:state_focused="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/focus_onfocus">
     </item>

     <item android:state_enabled="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/focus_offfocus">
     </item> 
   </selector>
   ```