# How to highlight an element in GridView?

Tags: android

I have a GridView with a BaseAdapter. I would highlight an element with its focus or selected or checked state.

I tried to set grid.setSelection(0) to highlight the first element, but nothing happened.

I set my drawable states background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666012/grid-view-item-not-hightlight-when-press

Answer (score 1):

put this code in `GetView()` Method of base adaptor

```
If(items[position] == selectedIndex){

  // Change background or something alpha or anything so that it looks like it is selected
}
```

And in `onItemSelected()` Method

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           int position,long id) {

         selectedIndex = position;
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Feel free to ask if you not get anything

Comment: I would to use the xml selector. I have a set of generated files and I want to highlight the last created.

Comment: sorry I am not getting you

Comment: I have a xml selector, and I'm looking for a way like gridview.setChecked(0) to get the checked state from the selector.

Comment: Hi Chirag ,can you pls help.. I have a grid view with image as a single item in grid When I m clicking in space left around image ,I get touch feedback from gridview but no feedback on clicking on the image.. what can I do? thanks.